# Adding new font to an Angular project

Tags: css, angular, fonts

I bought a new font type I would like to implement in my project.

The font file is in a .otf format.

I added the font file to my assets folder and did the following in my styles.css:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: p22-mackinac-pro !important;
   src: url('assets/fonts/P22Mackinac-Book.otf') format('otf');
   font-style: normal;
 }
```

When I add the font family in the body tag, nothing happens.

Now comes the most confusing part for me:

If a use the global selector and add the font family, it changes the font to another font, but not the font that I am using.

```
* {font-family: 'p22-mackinac-pro', serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
}
```

Lastly, part of the my sites font does not change at all unless I add "!important" to my global selector above, but this causes my angular icons to stop working!

This is the font I wish to have global in my project:

[image: See font here]

This is the font I get when I add the font family to my global selector in styles.css:

[image]

This is the font type on part of my project (when I don't add the !important" to font-family in styles.css to my global selector)

[image]

The css in my developer toolbar on chrome when I inspect the html that doesn't change:

[image]

Comment: Looks like youre using Angular Material. Check this link to see how to customize it: https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#customization

Comment: Since I'm using css and not scss I can't use the guide you are linking to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using material css which already have the font Roboto by default. So, eventually, your global font is overriden.

You'll need to override material's font by something like below.

```
h1 { font-family: 'p22-mackinac-pro', serif !important; }
```

Comment: This partly worked. I could add all the html tags in my styles.css and give the the font-family, but it doesn't seem right that I have to do it that way.

Comment: Also refer this link, in case you would like to override font with sass https://material.angular.io/guide/typography